# Discord.js Oauth2 with passport.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, oauth-2.0, passport.js

I'm having some bad days trying figuring out how to use the `refresh_token` provided by the `passport-discord` strategy.

I'm using `passport-oauth2-refresh` to obtain a new `accessToken` and `refreshToken`, but at this point i really don't know how to "refresh" the user object sent me by the passport-discord strategy

This is the entire strategy logic

```
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
  const user = await discordUser.findById(id);
  if (user) done(null, user);
});

const strat = new discordStrategy(
  {
    clientID: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: process.env.CLIENT_REDIRECT,
    scope: ["identify", "guilds"],
  },
  async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
    try {
      let user = await discordUser.findOne({ discordId: profile.id });
      if (user) {
        discordUser.findOneAndUpdate(
          { discordId: profile.id },
          { guilds: profile.guilds, rtoken: refreshToken, atoken: accessToken },

          async (err) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            let newUser = await discordUser.findOne({ discordId: profile.id });
            done(null, newUser);
          }
        );
      } else {
        const newUser = await discordUser.create({
          discordId: profile.id,
          username: profile.username,
          discriminator: profile.discriminator,
          avatar: profile.avatar,
          guilds: profile.guilds,
          rtoken: refreshToken,
          atoken: accessToken,
        });

        const savedUser = await newUser.save();

        done(null, savedUser);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      done(err, null);
    }
  }
);

passport.use("discord", strat);
refresh.use("discord", strat);
```

And this is the Express route that handle the login page

```
function isAuthorized(req, res, next) {
  if (req.user) {
    res.redirect("/");
  } else {
    next();
  }
}

router.get("/", passport.authenticate("discord"));
router.get(
  "/redirect",
  isAuthorized,
  passport.authenticate("discord", {
    failureRedirect: "/",
    successRedirect: "/close",
  })
);
```

I'm coding a web-dashboard that have to display all the guilds in witch the user have some special permissions...
I need to update the user object each time the user navigate to the route `/guilds`, because he could have created a new guilds, or get promoted etc...

Comment: Have you resolved your problem?

Comment: Explained in their [documentation](https://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-discord/), for anyone that has this question